# for row in spamreader: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 89: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I'm using the following piece of code in Python 2.7 to read data from a csv file encoded in `utf-8`. I'm using `codecs.open` with `encoding=utf-8` to read the text file, however, I keep getting the same issue.

```
import csv
import gensim
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import codecs

...

with codecs.open('data_techsupport.csv', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in spamreader:
        vectors.append([])
        x=list(row)
        x[0].encode('utf8')
        sentence=nltk.word_tokenize(x[0])

...
```

The **error** I get is:

```
for row in spamreader:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 89: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Python 2's `csv` module can't handle Unicode objects. You need to open the file in binary mode and work with the UTF-8 bytes. Or upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded to Python3 :-) Thanks for the help!